# Почему выходит за пределы массива

Tags: java

Задача:
Напишите программу, которая будет рассчитывать количество конечных нулей в факториале заданного числа.

Проблема: как планирую не работает, выходит за пределы массива + не сравнивает последний символ массива char с '0', чтобы прошло по условию.

```
int result = 1;
int count = 0;
// Считаем факториал
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    result = result * i;
}
char[] factorial = Integer.toString(result).toCharArray();
int length = factorial.length;
int i = 0;
// Здесь делаем поиск нулей. Сравниваем последний эл-нт массива.
while (i <= length) {
    if (factorial[length] == '0' && n > 1) {
        count++;
        length--;
    } else
        break;
}
return result;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, вы проверяете `factorial[length]`, где `length = factorial.length`. Опишу проблему на примере.

У вас факторил числа `10! = 3628800`. Соответственно, `length` в данном случае будет равно 7. И вы забираете сразу значение factorial[7] - такого элемента нет, т.к. отсчет в массиве начинается с 0 => чтобы проверить последнюю цифру, надо проверять `factorial[6]`, т.е. начальное условие будет `factorial[length - 1]`.

Во-вторых, если вы на вход подадите число, скажем 100, то у вас ничего не получится - проблема будет в том, что `100! > Integer.MAX_VALUE` - у вас будет переполнение и факториал правильно не посчитается.

Чтобы этого избежать - не надо вычислять сам факториал, нужно вычислять кол-во нулей в конце. Ноль на конце дает перемножение числа 5 на 2, либо же число кратное 10.

Answer (score 3):

Массивы нумеруются с нуля, поэтому последний индекс будет `length - 1` - вот и причина выхода за границу массива.

А вообще для решения этой задачи не нужно считать факториал. Подумайте, на каких значениях n добавляются нули в n!

Answer (score 0):

Демонстрация рабочего кода. Как раз то, что советовали другие.

```
 public class Solution {
       public static int zeros(int n) {
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 5; i <= n; i *= 5) {
      res += n / i;
    }
    return res;
  }
    }
```